# Boost::bind a sigaction function reference to a instance

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to use a Linux kernel signal to asynchronously communicate the occurrence of an event from a module to a user-space application. I have this working in C in the following way:

```
void rcv_signal(int n, siginfo_t *info, void *unused)
{
   // Do something interesting with the signal
}

// Register for updates from the kernel
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sig;
    sig.sa_sigaction = rcv_signal; // Function pointer
    sig.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SOME_CUSTOM_SIGNAL, &sig, NULL);

    // Code to wait() then return
}
```

Now, I would like to move to C++ implementation. More specifically, I would like to use boost::function / boost::bind to bind the sa_sigaction to a method `InputCapture::receive`. However, I am struggling to get the correct function signature.

Here is the definition of the InputCapture Class:

```
class InputCapture
{
    public: InputCapture(uint8_t intimer) : timer(_timer) {}
    public: ~InputCapture() {}
    private: void receive(int n, siginfo_t *info, void *unused) {}
    private: uint8_t timer;
};
```

And here is the modified sa_sigaction:

```
// Register for updates from the kernel
struct sigaction sig;
sig.sa_sigaction = boost::function<void (int n, siginfo_t *info, void *unused)> (
    boost::bind(&InputCapture::receive, this, _1));
sig.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(SOME_CUSTOM_SIGNAL, &sig, NULL);
```

However, I get the following compilation error:

> In file included from /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
>                    from /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/LogicalStamp.hpp:12,
>                    from /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.hpp:4,
>                    from /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp:1:
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::_bi::result_traits’:
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:48:   required from ‘class boost::_bi::bind_t)(int, siginfo, void*), boost::_bi::list2, boost::arg<1> > >’
>   /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp:41:57:   required from here
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: ‘void (timesync::InputCapture::*)(int, siginfo*, void*)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
>        typedef typename F::result_type type;
>                                        ^
>   /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp: In constructor ‘timesync::InputCapture::InputCapture(uint8_t)’:
>   /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp:40:19: error: cannot convert ‘boost::function’ to ‘void (*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*) {aka void (*)(int, siginfo*, void*)}’ in assignment
>     sig.sa_sigaction = boost::function (
>                      ^
>   In file included from /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:28:0,
>                    from /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
>                    from /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:62,
>                    from /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
>                    from /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp:3:
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker3::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t)(int, siginfo, void*), boost::_bi::list2, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = int; T1 = siginfo*; T2 = void*]’:
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:907:38:   required from ‘void boost::function3::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t)(int, siginfo, void*), boost::_bi::list2, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = int; T1 = siginfo*; T2 = void*]’
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function3::function3(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t)(int, siginfo, void*), boost::_bi::list2, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = int; T1 = siginfo*; T2 = void*; typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1042:16:   required from ‘boost::function::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t)(int, siginfo, void*), boost::_bi::list2, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = int; T1 = siginfo*; T2 = void*; typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
>   /home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp:41:58:   required from here
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:57: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_bi::bind_t)(int, siginfo, void*), boost::_bi::list2, boost::arg<1> > >) (int&, siginfo*&, void*&)’
>              BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN((*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
>                                                            ^
>   /home/asymingt/export/rootfs/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:75:36: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN’
>    #  define BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(X) X

Is what I am trying to achieve possible, and if so, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: are you missing _2 and _3 after the _1 in your bind?  Your callback is accepting 3 arguments so I think you need all 3 dummy arguments in the bind as well

Comment: Good spot -- you are correct. However, it still does not seem to work. I receive an error: `/home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp: In constructor ‘timesync::InputCapture::InputCapture(uint8_t)’:
/home/asymingt/Workspace/Source/roseline/timesync/src/stamp/InputCapture.cpp:40:19: error: cannot convert ‘boost::function<void(int, siginfo*, void*)>’ to ‘void (*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*) {aka void (*)(int, siginfo*, void*)}’ in assignment
  sig.sa_sigaction = boost::function<void (int n, siginfo_t *info, void *unused)> (

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the different between siginfo_t and siginfo* in the function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.

Note that `sigaction::sa_sigaction` is a pointer to function. Neither `boost::function`, nor the return value of `boost::bind` are convertible to a function pointer!

Comment: Thanks, Igor. Do you know if there a C++ equivalent of sigation that I can use, which would allow me to bind to a member function?

Comment: @Andrew `sigaction` is a plain C function. For C++ equivalent, you can take a look at Boost.Asio library that provides [`signal_set` object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html).