# Obtaining the sig_int value from siginfo in boost::siginfo handler

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio

I have a custom signal that is emitted from a kernel module to user space in the following way. Note that I include an integer (id) in the `si_int` struct parameter attached to the signal, and I already know the pid of the user-space app I am targeting.

```
struct siginfo info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
info.si_signo = MY_CUSTOM_SIGNAL;
info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;        // Fake coming from user-space
info.si_int = id;               // Include some variable id
send_sig_info(MY_CUSTOM_SIGNAL, &info, pid);
```

In my user-space application I listen for the signal in the following way:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::signal_set signals(io, MY_CUSTOM_SIGNAL);
signals.async_wait(handler);
io.run();
```

... and this handler is called when it occurs ...

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number)
{
    // Do something with the signal
}
```

Unfortunately, the siginfo is not passed into the handler, so I am unable to determine the value of the `id` variable assigned by the kernel module. Is there any way to determine this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

In the presence of [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), Boost.Asio registers its internal signal handler as `sa_handler` and does not set the `SA_SIGINFO` flag.  Hence, Boost.Asio's signal handler never receives the `siginfo_t` associated with the signal, and cannot propagate it to the user's [SignalHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SignalHandler.html) when completing the `async_wait()` operation.  Here is the relevant excerpt from the [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp#L274-L279):

```cpp
using namespace std; // For memset.
struct sigaction sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sa_handler = boost_asio_signal_handler;
sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
if (::sigaction(signal_number, &sa, 0) == -1)
```

---

Given your recent question about [having a functor handle a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29901633/1053968) and Boost.Asio only receiving and propagating `signum`, it may be worth considering implementing your own signal handler using the [self-pipe trick](https://www.google.com/?#q=self-pipe+trick).  However, where as Boost.Asio only [writes](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp#L71-L72) and [reads](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp#L99-L103) `signum` on the pipe, one could write and read additional information, such as `siginfo.si_int`.